# How to add hook on submit registration in wordpress to drupal?

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

I have to write a hook on registered Wordpress user to Drupal user registration. On submit Wordpress registration it should insert username, password, etc to the Drupal database as well.

drupal version(7.50)

wordpress version(4.6.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress current active theme functions.php file

```
  add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save');
    function myplugin_registration_save( ) {

           //extract data from the post
        //set POST variables
        $url = 'http://xxxxxx.com/drupal/drupal_hook_register.php';
        $fields = array(
            'email' => urlencode($_POST['email']),
            'password' => urlencode($_POST['password'])

        );

        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string, '&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);


}
```

And in Drupal site root directory create a file(drupal_hook_register.php). this function will insert all the wordpress registration fields into drupal database directly.

```
          // define static var
          define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

        // include bootstrap
        include_once('./includes/bootstrap.inc');
         // initialize stuff
           drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

//This will generate a random password, you could set your own here
  //$password = user_password(8);

  //set up the user fields



 $fields = array(



     'mail' => $email,
        'pass' => $password,
        'status' => 1,
        'init' => 'email address',
        'roles' => array(
          DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
        ),
      );


  //the first parameter is left blank so a new user is created
  $account = user_save('', $fields);

  //print_r($account);

  // If you want to send the welcome email, use the following code

  // Manually set the password so it appears in the e-mail.
  $account->password = $fields['pass'];

  // Send the e-mail through the user module.
  //drupal_mail('user', 'register_no_approval_required', $email, NULL, array('account' => $account), variable_get('site_mail', 'noreply@example..com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When user register in wordpress site create user in wordpress and as well get POST values send to Drupal website using RESTful web service.

REF : https://www.drupal.org/project/restful

user registration hook in wordpress : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Comment: @mike implement REST in drupal and check with postman, then send POST value to drupal website by CURL. its a big process. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview

Comment: i have added thr curl functionaltiy how to hook user insert in drupal php page. i have a seperate page for do that